# flutter migration: where to move java init code when migrating to the Android embedding v2

Tags: flutter

On migration page https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

It said `remove` the whole `onCreate(_)` function as bellow,

but where should my code in this function moved to  ?

```java
private FlutterMyOnePlugin flutterMyOnePlugin;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
   // my codes bellow here

   // init my plugin
   flutterMyOnePlugin = FlutterMyOnePlugin.registerWith(this);

   // this is for notification on one Phone Platform
   if(Utils.isHuaweiPhone()) {
        AVMixPushManager.connectHMS(MainActivity.this);
        AVMixPushManager.turnOnHMSPush(MainActivity.this, new AVCallback<Void>() {
           @Override
           protected void internalDone0(Void aVoid, AVException avException){}
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested to remove `onCreate` only if your code is calling

```java
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
```

As this will be automatically be taken care of. Doesn't mean you have to necessarily remove your init code too. Just omit this one line and it should be fine

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#changes-specific-to-add-to-app

```java
package [your.package.name];

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  // Emphasis here
  // You do not need to override onCreate() in order to invoke
  // GeneratedPluginRegistrant. Flutter now does that on your behalf.

  // ...retain whatever custom code you had from before (if any).
}
```

Edit ----
I think it would work fine even if not the add-to-app scenario. You only remove the onCreate method if it contains the single invoke of `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);`

Otherwise just put your init code in onCreate as usual. Here is a working example of my production app for listening to messaging service. Works fine

```
class Activity : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel = NotificationChannel("messages", "Messages", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
            val manager: NotificationManager? = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry!!)
    }
}
```

Comment: my app is pure flutter app, just created long time ago, I don't thinks it's `Add-to-app scenarios `

Comment: if remove the `onCreate`, where would be the `notification on one Phone Platform ` code to put to be called when app start ?

Comment: OK, thanks, so, should I keep `import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;` , and not use `import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;`  ?

Comment: Yup do that. Also my suggestion; instead of using a FlutterActivity for init code, you can place this all in a FltterApplication derived class. And point your application name in Manifest to this class. It's my preferred way. Doesn't change much

Comment: You have explained well, but I still get some error to run in android studio... still checking..

Comment: Error? Can you update your question with that? I get a missing reference here and then but runs fine on the app.

Comment: Oh, 1.  I need to add the splash in `step 4`;   2. I need to comment out an plugin which build error with latest flutter version..    let me check if it works then.

Comment: Now I can run the flutter project with Android Studio.   but when I run it with VSCode, it still show me the error: The plugin `audio_streamer` requires your app to be migrated to the Android embedding v2. Follow the steps on https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration and re-run this command.

Comment: Now the error is ` MainActivity can't convert to FlutterEngine
    ShimPluginRegistry shimPluginRegistry = new ShimPluginRegistry(flutterEngine);`